# How to disable NERDTree buffer when opening certain file types

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Currently the NERDTree buffer opens for every file that you open. If I'm writing to *.scala, *.py, etc. But I don't want this to happen for certain files that I'm writing (such as Haskell). For example, when I'm opening a Haskell file, I don't want the NERDTree buffer to open as soon as I type in `vim file.hs` in the terminal. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably use something like this in your `~/.vimrc` to automatically open NERDTree:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

You just need to add a conditional, e.g. to suppress the opening when *any* files are passed to Vim:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | NERDTree | endif
```

As the VimEnter command fires after buffers have been loaded, you can also check for the current `'filetype'` value to suppress only, say, Haskell files:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * if &filetype !=# 'haskell' | NERDTree | endif
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingo-Karat! That worked perfectly. I need to look more into Vimscript.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to close the question by accepting the answer (click on the check mark).